# Sodium X25519 Xsalsa20 Poly1305 decrypt message in PHP

Tags: php, cryptography, sodium

I want to decrypt a message but I'm somehow stuck.

What I receive:

```
content: CiA1e7UXqb5/4S5YfHJuKVZUxfdEW5QJAQUKlbDdN81WvxJAIBBjEvGwABl7El54KKqczSJmCqJOUzuzlp9o+7iiL0RgPbtnqZNdq5XjyeJuJoPjxqJ6Ya2mMv....
envelopeHash: Aac3P5NIWEEwOgtIdJV+QoyTK3YferKCguhuMR/+qJJY
```

what I got:

public key from the sender
my public and privat key (all keys as hex).

Now I'm new to crypto things and I'm unsure what I should do with the envelopeHash. I tried:

```
sodium_crypto_box_seal_open(base64_decode(content), key pair (public key from sender, my privat key)
sodium_crypto_box_open(base64_decode(content), nonce(envelopeHash ), key pair)
```

I used the envelopeHash as nonce but it's too big

> Uncaught SodiumException: nonce size should be SODIUM_CRYPTO_BOX_NONCEBYTES bytes

So I'm kinda lost with that. Maybe someone knows what this envelopeHash thing is?

Comment: XSalsa20 is a stream cipher based upon Salsa20 but with a much longer nonce: 192 bits instead of 64 bits. - The envelopeHash is 256 bits in your question. What method/lib/function did you use to encrypt?

Comment: Well i don't know which method they used. It's a closed source project so i need to figure it out. I only know that they used libsodium for the encryption.